# Why Buffer copy prints me some garbage value?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js,

I was reading on Node.js Buffers.

I stumbled on buffer.copy method.

Wrote a code which is as follows,

```
var bufferOne = new Buffer("This is China");
var bufferTwo = new Buffer(20),
   startTarget = 0,
   sourceStart = 8,
   sourceEnd = 0;
var bufferLength = bufferOne.length;
sourceEnd = bufferLength;
console.log("Buffer length "+bufferLength);
bufferOne.copy(bufferTwo,startTarget,sourceStart,sourceEnd);

console.log("Buffer1 "+bufferOne.toString());   
console.log("Buffer2 "+bufferTwo.toString());
```

The output is as follows,

```
Buffer length 13
Buffer1 This is China
Buffer2 China
```

But sometimes it also prints garbage output after "China", as follows,

```
Buffer length 13
Buffer1 This is China
Buffer2 China���*�
```

Sometimes,

```
Buffer length 13
Buffer1 This is China
Buffer2 China���
```

Can somebody please tell me whats going on ?

Comment: I m pretty sure it is because you copied in a buffer too large, and end up printing undefined value, which translate in garbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of `bufferTwo` is 20, but you're only copying 13 bytes. The remaining 7 bytes contain semi-random data.

Documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer_from_buffer_alloc_and_buffer_allocunsafe):

> Passing a number as the first argument to `Buffer()` (e.g. `new Buffer(10)`), allocates a new `Buffer` object of the specified size. The memory allocated for such `Buffer` instances is *not* initialized and *can contain sensitive data*.